# Sinatra json rendering not working as expected

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm having a problem in Sinatra where I can't respond with just a json and I can't find good sinatra docs anywhere, most of things seems outdated.

Anyways, here's the code:

```
module MemcachedManager
  class App < Sinatra::Base
    register Sinatra::Contrib
    helpers Sinatra::JSON

    get '/' do
      json({ hello: 'world' })
    end
  end
end

MemcachedManager::App.run! if __FILE__ == $0
```

The response that I do get is:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><p>{\"hello\":\"world\"}</p></body></html>\n"
```

Where it should have been only the json part. Why is it rendering html tags when I didn't ask for it?

Comment: do you have some layout configured?

Comment: @thiagofm - did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you seen [this blog post](http://nathanhoad.net/how-to-return-json-from-sinatra)?

```
require 'json'

get '/example.json' do
  content_type :json
  { :key1 => 'value1', :key2 => 'value2' }.to_json
end
```

I would also modify this to:

```
get '/example.json', :provides => :json do
```

to stop HTML/XML calls using the route. Since you're using the sinatra-contrib gem, and since Ruby doesn't need all those parens etc, you can also simplify the code you've given as an example to:

```
require 'sinatra/json'

module MemcachedManager    
  class App < Sinatra::Base
    helpers Sinatra::JSON
    get '/', :provides => :json do
      json hello: 'world'
    end
  end
end

MemcachedManager::App.run! if __FILE__ == $0
```

Comment: still getting <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><p>{\"hello\":\"world\"}</p></body></html>\n

Comment: @thiagofm What are you using to make the request? RSpec? cURL? Chrome…?

Comment: i'm only doing a get into the page and getting it's response body.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
content_type :json
```

before the `json(...)` call